# Having trouble assigning a new variant array from another array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to read a range that has data as:

```
date&time    price1 price2 price3 price4
```

and lots of rows going back many months/years (multiple entries per day). In the first instance, I'm trying to read this as a range from the spreadsheet, load it into a variant array and then cycle through the array only picking the data for a particular day. Once I have that (I call it `today_data`) I'll then do more calculations on it. Right now, I have defined the new array (`today_data` as `variant`), and Excel VBA is not allowing me to assign a value to it from the bigger array. I'm new to this please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
Function test1(td As Long) As Variant

Dim rg As Range
Dim n, m As Long
Dim i, j, k As Long


'intra day data is an n by m array
'i and j are counters for the loops
'td is today's date from the spreadsheet

Dim iday_data As Variant    ' this is the full array of intra-day data
Dim today_data As Variant   ' this is today's intra-day data


    Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("i7:m3201")
    iday_data = rg
    n = UBound(iday_data, 1)
    m = UBound(iday_data, 2)
    k = 1


For i = 1 To n

        today_data(k, 1) = iday_data(i, 1)    'this is where the program halts
        today_data(k, 2) = iday_data(i, 2)
        today_data(k, 3) = iday_data(i, 3)
        today_data(k, 4) = iday_data(i, 4)
        k = k + 1

Next i

test1 = today_data
```

Comment: You have not declared a size to the `today_data` array

Comment: Thank you Scott, the problem is that I do not know what size the today_data is going to be exactly, I can guess it depending on the daily interval and the number of approximate bars in one day, at worst it will be as long as the original array. whats the best thing to do ?  thank you again

Comment: well right now you are doing a one for one on the rows. so make it the same size as the iday_data array.  If you are going to add an If statement then use `Application.CountIfs()` with the criteria to find the extent.  Or you can use `Redim Preserve`  There are a lot of methods to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `ReDim Preserve`.

1. I have assumed the date is formatted as a date and is in column I and that you want to compare this against long passed into function as `td` argument. So I have added in a test line for qualifying rows with: `If DateValue(iday_data(1, jColumn)) = td Then`
2. As you only work with 4 columns, I restrict range read in to end at L.
3. I first swop rows and columns as you can only redim the outer dimension. You will be wanting the matching row count for column 1 so I switched these around with `Transpose` and later swop them back again after the `ReDim Preserve` at the end. There are some limitations to row oount with `Transpose`.
4. `43267` was "16/06/2018", format "dd-mm-yyyy", passed in as a numeric value i.e. td argument for date comparison which expects a `Long`.

---

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Testing()
    Dim arr()
    arr = test1(43267)
    Stop

End Sub

Public Function test1(ByVal td As Long) As Variant
    Dim targetRange As Range, numberOfRows As Long, numberOfColumns As Long
    Dim iRow As Long, jColumn As Long, columnCounter As Long
    Dim iday_data(), today_data()

    Set targetRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I7:L3201") 'Assume L not M as you only work with 4 columns.
    iday_data = targetRange
    iday_data = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(iday_data) 'swop rows and columns
    numberOfRows = UBound(iday_data, 1)
    numberOfColumns = UBound(iday_data, 2)

    ReDim today_data(1 To numberOfRows, 1 To numberOfColumns)

    For iRow = LBound(iday_data, 1) To UBound(iday_data, 1) 'loop between Bounds
        columnCounter = 1
        For jColumn = LBound(iday_data, 2) To UBound(iday_data, 2)
            'Note date value assume Date format in sheet and you want to compare against long passed into function as td argument
            '<== Add in your date/day of interest. Compare against which ever column of iday_data has the day of interest in e.g. 1.
            If DateValue(iday_data(1, jColumn)) = td Then
                today_data(iRow, columnCounter) = iday_data(iRow, jColumn)
                columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ReDim Preserve today_data(1 To numberOfRows, 1 To columnCounter)
    today_data = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(today_data) 'swop rows and columns
    test1 = today_data
End Function
```